# How can i show user avatar image using xmpp framework in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am creating a chat application for iPhone using XMPPFramework. I want to display user list in UITableView with user name and photo, and for this I am using

```
NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];
if (photoData != nil)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
else
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image~iPhone.png"];
```

but it returns nil always.

Please help..

Comment: What returns nil ? photoData ?

Comment: `if (photoData)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];`

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData *photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid]);

if (photoData)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
else
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image~iPhone.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine.

**photoDataForJID** method returns NSData.

```
NSData *avtarData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

if (avtarData)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
else
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image~iPhone.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

             NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


if (imgData)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
else
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_user.png"];
            });
        });
```